# How to change theme of MVC in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, templates, asp.net-mvc-templates

i am using default template of Asp.net MVC 3 but now want to move to MVC 4, i have completed my project but now exporting it to MVC 4. Actually i want only the template of MVC 4 to be applied to my MVC 3 made app. How ?

I do have files in folders. What are possibilities ?

Answer (score 0):

The "Themes" folder in MVC is just a feature of jQuery UI and is not an MVC-specific feature. MVC itself does not have any actual "theme" support.

You can find additional themes as NuGet packages from the NuGet feed: [Here](http://nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3a%22jQueryUI%22%20themes)

Comment: Download the theme and save in a folder. In your _Layout.cshtml you need to specify the theme by adding the styles